# Spring batch upgrade from 2.1.x to 4.2.x

Tags: spring-batch

we would like our Spring batch to upgrade from version 2.1.x to latest 4.2.x. Initial assessment suggests Spring batch admin manager has been deprecated and replaced by spring cloud data flow. Our organization is not looking for any Spring cloud solutions as heavily invested in other cloud solutions. I am interested to understand on

1. What is the alternate solution of spring admin manager
2. High level upgradation steps

Thanks in advance for your assistance in this regard.

Regards

Prashant S

Comment: Anyone out there who can help on above question please?